# Integrate $\int \tan \left( a_0 \, e^{(-x/L)} \right) \,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm stuck on an integral

$$\int \tan \left( a_0 \, e^{(-x/L)} \right) \,dx $$

where $a_0$ is a constant.

I've tried doing a substitution with $ u = a_0e^{x/L}$ but it gave me

$$\int \frac{\tan(u)}{u}du $$ which Wolfram Alpha didn't like.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for the indefinite integral i see not many chances. Maybe if there are some limits

Comment: If $u=a_0 e^{x/L}$ then $du= \frac{1}{L} u dx$. However, please note that inside your integral you have $u=a_0 e^{-{x/L}}$ so I suppose you use these substitution since the argument of your tangent is just u. In this case your integral becomes: 
\begin{equation}
-L \int{\frac{tan(u)}{u} du}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Just like other [trigonometric integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral), it does not possess a closed form expression. See also [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html). This can be proven using either [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) or the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). Alternately, expand $\tan(x)$ into its well-known [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions), then reverse the order of summation and integration.